# Unable to parse the rows in ResultSet returned by connection.execute(), Python and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a task to compare data of two tables in two different oracle databases. We have access of views in both of db. Using SQLAlchemy ,am able to fetch rows from views but unable to parse it.

In one db the type of ID column is : Raw

In db where column type is "Raw", below is the row am getting from resultset .

(b'\x0b\x975z\x9d\xdaF\x0e\x96>[*Ig\xe0/', 1, datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 7, 12, 11, 1), None, datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 7, 12, 11, 1), b'\xf2X\x8b\x86\x03\x00K|\x99(\xbc\x81n\xc6*\xd3', None, 'I', 'Inactive')

ID Column data: b'\x0b\x975z\x9d\xdaF\x0e\x96>[_Ig\xe0/'

Actual data in ID column in database: F2588B8603004B7C9928BC816EC65FD3

This data is not complete hexadecimal format as it has some speical symbols like >|[_ etc. I want to know that how can I parse the data in ID column and get it as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bytes.hex() solved the problem